# InvalidFirebaseData during Sign Up process

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

Currently, I am using a combination of Firebase authentication, database, and storage for my sign up process.

```
@objc func handleSignUp() {

        guard let email = emailTextField.text else { return }
        guard let password = passwordTextField.text else { return }
        guard let fullName = fullNameTextField.text else { return }
        guard let username = usernameTextField.text else { return }

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in

            //handle error
            if let error = error {

                print("Failed to create user with error", error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            //set profile image
            guard let profileImage = self.plusPhotoButton.imageView?.image else { return }

            //upload data
            guard let uploadData = profileImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) else { return }

            //place image in firbase storage
            let filename = NSUUID().uuidString

            let storage = Storage.storage()
            let storageReference = storage.reference()

            let imagesReference = storageReference.child("profile_images")

            let uploadReference = imagesReference.child(filename)
            uploadReference.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in

                //handle error
                if let error = error {

                    print("Failed to upload image to Firebase Storage with error", error.localizedDescription)
                }

                //profile image url
                let profileImageURL = uploadReference.downloadURL

                //user id
                let uid = user?.user.uid

                let dictionaryValues = ["name": fullName, "username": username, "profileImageURL": profileImageURL]

                let values = [uid: dictionaryValues]

                //save user info to database
                Database.database().reference().child("users").updateChildValues(values) { (error, ref) in

                    print("Successfully created user and saved information to database")

                }
            }
        }
```

This should be the code, which should be working fine.
However, xCode is giving me this error:

> Heterogeneous collection literal could only be inferred to '[String : Any]'; add explicit type annotation if this is intentional

and is advising me to change

```
let dictionaryValues = ["name": fullName, "username": username, "profileImageURL": profileImageURL]
```

to

```
let dictionaryValues = ["name": fullName, "username": username, "profileImageURL": profileImageURL] as [String : Any]
```

As a result, I can compile and run the project.

However, when I press the sign-up button and therefore run the given function, the console is showing this error:

> 2019-09-30 19:15:13.049986+0200 5iveli0ns[965:28839] [] nw_connection_receive_internal_block_invoke [C2] Receive reply failed with error "Operation canceled"

and in the end I receive a Runtime Exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(updateChildValues:withCompletionBlock:) Cannot store object of type __SwiftValue at profileImageURL. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.'

Is this an xCode 11 / Firebase 5.x.x related issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, Dictionaries infer their structure from the data they contain. So for example

```
let dict = [
   "name": "Leroy",
   "fav_food": "Pizza"
]
```

is a [String: String] Dictionary

Likewise

```
let dict = [
   "name": "Leroy"
   "age": 25
]
```

is a [String: Int] Dictionary.

What you have is

```
let dict = [
   "name": "Leroy",
   "username": "some username"
   "profileImageUrl": URL //oops, not a string, its a URL!
]
```

When Dictionary values are consistent, they can be defined [String: String]. However, when the value types will vary, they are [String: Any]

The other issue is that Firebase doesn't support the URL type, so even if you used a Dictionary of [String: Any], Firebase will complain - as shown by the error.

The fix is easy - just use the path, which is a string of the url

```
if let url = uploadReference.downloadURL {
    let path = url
    let dict = [
       "name": "Leroy",
       "username": "some username",
       "path": path //it's a string
    ]
    //write dict to Firebase
}
```

Answer (score 0):

COnvert

```
let profileImageURL = uploadReference.downloadURL
```

to String then feed it into the dictionaryValues array.

I hope that helps